# How to fix an error about PATH when installing tensorflow on windows?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow2.0

I tried to install tensorflow, but I got the following error:

My Command:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

The Error I got:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'C:\\Users\\sipha\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0
\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include
\\external\\com_github_grpc_grpc\\src\\core\\ext\\filters\\client_channel
\\lb_policy\\grpclb\\client_load_reporting_filter.h'

HINT: This error might have occurred since this system does not have
Windows Long Path support enabled. You can find information on how to
enable this at https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/enable-long-paths
```

anyone know how to make new envirenment?

install tensoCMDrflow on windows, worked with CMD.

have python version 3.10

Comment: Never had a problem with this. Maybe your Python installation is the issue. Try installing to C:\Python\version.number and fix the environment variables to use from this path. Also, what version of Windows do you have?

Comment: Have window 11 in my laptop, im trying in windows 10, but always the same problem.

Comment: Try using a different Python installation on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Long Path is disabled on your PC.
Do the following to enable it, and then try to install Tensorflow.

1. Press the Windows key + R key.
2. Type regedit and press enter.
3. Navigate to the following location `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` in the registry editor(regedit), or you could just paste it in the search bar on top.
4. Find and right click on `LongPathsEnabled`
5. Set the DWORD value to 1 instead of zero and reboot your computer.

This will enable Long Path support. Then try to install Tensorflow again.

You could reference the following article if you need any help https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/.

Answer (score 0):

try conda install instead of pip install if you have conda installed

conda install tensorflow==2.6.0